# Problem with making multiple images draggable

Tags: html

I'm trying to make multiple images on a website draggable and include an ondblclick function to send me to a different link(for later on). Right now I can move the top img but the second image can't be moved at all and only the double clicks work perfectly and individually for both elements. 
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
</style>
<body>

<div id="mydiv">
  <img src="_dsc5502.jpg" name="bild06" class="BILDER" style="position:absolute; z-index:7; left: 639px; top: 146px;" ondblclick="javascript:alert('event has been TRIGGERED');">
</div>

<div id="mydiv">
  <img src="_dsc5494.jpg" name="bild05" class="BILDER" style="position:absolute; z-index:6; left: 690px; top: 34px;" ondblclick="javascript:alert('event has been triggered');">
</div>

<script>
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions for making both elements draggable would be a major help. Thanks so much in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow, if I undertood you well you can do it easily. Please, check your code again, you are not selecting the second `div` Apart from that there are some concepts that you should check like `img` tags, `ids`, inline styles and so on. You can make draggable the images directly : )

```js
// Make the images draggable:
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach($img => dragElement($img))

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0
  elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://media.prod.mdn.mozit.cloud/attachments/2019/07/15/16797/4c169938d5f923bfa4db5ee937f24ebe/clock-demo-400px.png">
<img src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg" ondblclick="javascript:alert('event has been triggered');">
```

Hope this help, keep going and study hard ^^